# Error when compiling sample GWT Gadget app

Tags: java, gwt, google-gadget

I am trying to get the GWT sample Gadgets app to run based on the example given [here](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/GadgetsGettingStarted). When I compile the code I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.gadgets.rebind.GadgetGenerator.validateType(GadgetGenerator.java:353)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.gadgets.rebind.GadgetGenerator.generate(GadgetGenerator.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:676)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:644)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:34)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:271)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:223)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:139)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:167)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:132)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
```

I have the following major dependencies for my project:

1. gwt-user v2.6.1
2. gwt-gadgets v1.0.3

I am using java 1.7

Can someone please tell me what I am missing... been googling the whole day and found nothing useful

Answer (score 1):

gwt-gadgets 1.0.3 was compiled a long time before GWT 2.6.1. It sounds like there might be some breaking changes in GWT which affect gwt-gadgets calls into gwt-user.

You should be able to get the source for gwt-gadgets and fix/compile it against a more recent version of gwt-user, or failing that you might have to use an older GWT more in line with the release date of gwt-gadgets 1.0.3 (May 2009!)